# Align JTextFields in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am looking for a solution to align two `JTextFields` with different sizes in a `GridBagLayout`. Instead of maintaining the original size of the `JTextField` I would prefer both to end in the same column.

```
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    gbc.ipady =  10;

    JLabel lb1 = new JLabel("User: ");
    JLabel lb2 = new JLabel("Name: ");
    JLabel lb3 = new JLabel("First ");
    JLabel nameLB = new JLabel("Last ");
    JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField nameTF = new JTextField(20);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(lb1,gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    add(lb2,gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    add(tf1,gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    add(lb3,gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    add(tf2,gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    add(nameLB,gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    add(nameTF,gbc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume tf1 is what causing the issue. If this text field is not extending to the end you could add the fill constraint. Try

```
gbc.fill =  GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
pane.add(tf1, gbc);
```

If this is not working can you post your full code or more description about your problem?